# Difference between int() and int(input())

Tags: python, input, int

If I type `int(6.5)` on the interpreter prompt, the output is 6.

If I type `int(input())`, and give 6.5 as an input, then it gives an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6.5'
```

What is happening here?

Comment: `int(6.5)` is different to `int('6.5')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input() function takes string as input.
It is equivalent to doing int('6.5') which is different from int(6.5) -> Casting double/float to int.